# Starting page number from 1 after an odd section break

Tags: ms-word, openxml

So I'm using a the OpenXml SDK to create reports, and am trying to create the Word doc layout manually before attempting to implement it programmatically.

These reports will have sections that should start on a new page, and each new section should have a page number that starts from 1.

The peculiar thing is if you edit the page number field to start from 1 after the odd section break then the page after the odd section break can go to an even page.

To see what I mean you can download this test document:

https://mega.co.nz/#!ek4DRATT!XKei7kGrM5_HammDJDcbavz_vutgwv4DfncFgn7NJ1o

And edit the page number field on page 3 to start from 1. Page 3 will become page 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I eventually found out that to do this you need to make different odd and even footers are enabled in Page Setup:

[image: Screenshot]